# check whether an icon is on a picture

Tags: opencv, testing, computer-vision, automated-tests

I try to automate an application's test, but I fail to complete the checkpoint. The problem is that when the application's test finishes one test step, and the checkpoint needs to find whether the designed icon is showed on the screen. The application is in VR mode, so the screenshot has do some transform on it. Is there some way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try different approaches, depends on the nature of your problem.

1. Try [template matching](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html), if the transforms aren't too serious it should peak at the right location.
2. If you can - get the VR transform and invert it.
3. I would probably do [feature matching](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html). It should also be pretty robust to the transforms you are referring to.